# Python OpenCV pause without ending on error

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading a video using OpenCV:

```
def get_frames(video_path):
    # Generate frames
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        try:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret is True:
                yield frame
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

for _ in get_frames(input_video_path_1):
    # do stuff
```

When running my process I got the following errors:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x7feec69d4400] ac-tex damaged at 21 17
[mpeg4 @ 0x7feec69d4400] Error at MB: 1398
```

The problem is that no python error is raised and therefore I cannot catch the error. The code seems to pause without ending. It just stops there. How can I at least catch the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there are two issues with the code:

1. OpenCV documentation was reporting a wrong example on how to read a video file. See more here: https://forum.opencv.org/t/python-opencv-pause-without-ending-on-error/2090
2. It is not possible to catch those errors.